# Manipulate csv file using bash script or python, converting certain columns into rows

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I have a csv file with 6 columns. I want to write a script using Python or Bash so that I can generate a new file, maybe a txt file, where for each row the first three columns remain the same (that is column 1, 2 and 3 remain in same rows), but the next three columns (i.e. columns 4, 5 ,6) get inserted into a new row, just below their previous row.

My sample file looks like this:

```
Column1   Column2    Column3     Column4    Column5      Column6
chr16    2697996    2697997     chr16      2086192      2086193
chr5    112801382   112801383   chr5       138445682    138445683
chr15   26869333    26869334    chr8       119416385    119416386
```

My final file should look like this:

```
Column1  Column2     Column3
chr16   2697996     2697997
chr16   2086192     2086193
chr5    112801382   112801383
chr5    138445682   138445683
chr15   26869333    26869334
chr8    119416385   119416386
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting for example input and output text. http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `awk` approach:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if((i%4)==0) printf "\n"; printf "%s%s",$i,FS;}printf "\n"} END{printf "\n"}' input.csv
chr16 2697996 2697997 
chr16 2086192 2086193 
chr5 112801382 112801383 
chr5 138445682 138445683 
chr15 26869333 26869334 
chr8 119416385 119416386
```

Assuming the "Columns" is present in the file, it'd be easier to process the file without them, hence `NR>1` part. After that is a simple for-loop, which inserts a newline whenever there's no remainder in integer division by 4 in the column number ( the `(i%4) == 0` part ). This is a very common trick to deal with short counters or data that needs to occur at specific intervals. Newline is necessary because we're printing data via `printf` directly as plain string, not a full line.

---

Since you've requested python, here's a python script as well:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    for index,line in enumerate(fd):

        items=line.strip().split()
        if index == 0:
            print(" ".join(items[:len(items)//2]))
            continue

        left = items[:len(items)//2]
        right = items[len(items)//2:]
        print( " ".join(left) )
        print( " ".join(right) )
```

Works as follows:

```
$ ./break_columns.py ./input.csv 
Column1 Column2 Column3
chr16 2697996 2697997
chr16 2086192 2086193
chr5 112801382 112801383
chr5 138445682 138445683
chr15 26869333 26869334
chr8 119416385 119416386
```

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: @AnkitaSrivastava See update on the answer.

Comment: Hey hi!  I want now exactly opposite of this by which I mean the output file should be processed to look like input file can you please help me with the same.

Comment: @AnkitaSrivastava Sure. Just make a separate post, and perhaps link this one in it. As far as I recall, there's gotta be a question already doing something like this, but it'll be very hard to  find, so just make a new question

Comment: Hey I got the answer. Yes there was already a question for this. :) I am using                           paste -d " "  - - < filename

Answer (score 0):

You can use Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and a bash script. Starting from input

```
Column1   Column2    Column3     Column4    Column5      Column6
chr16    2697996    2697997     chr16      2086192      2086193
chr5    112801382   112801383   chr5       138445682    138445683
chr15   26869333    26869334    chr8       119416385    119416386
```

and running

```
<input tail -n +2 | mlr --nidx --ifs ' ' --repifs cut -f 1,2,3 >out_01
<input tail -n +2 | mlr --nidx --ifs ' ' --repifs cut -f 4,5,6 >out_02

mlr --nidx --ifs ' ' --repifs cat out_01 out_02 >out

mlr -I --n2c --fs ' ' cat then label Column1,Column2,Column3 out
```

you will have

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
chr16 2697996 2697997
chr5 112801382 112801383
chr15 26869333 26869334
chr16 2086192 2086193
chr5 138445682 138445683
chr8 119416385 119416386
```

If you want a pretty printed output, change the final command in `mlr -I --n2p --fs ' ' cat then label Column1,Column2,Column3 out`

```
Column1 Column2   Column3
chr16   2697996   2697997
chr5    112801382 112801383
chr15   26869333  26869334
chr16   2086192   2086193
chr5    138445682 138445683
chr8    119416385 119416386
```